# How to get info from class to private member?

Tags: java, oop

I am writing a system that has several classes. There is  one class that stores as a private field, an instance of another class. The second class needs to know information about the private fields in the first class. Can this be done?

EDIT: I am trying to make a "house"; this includes rooms and people

The way I have it organized there is an instance of the People class in the Room class. However, the room number, which is stored in the room, needs to be known to each instance of People. So how do I get this information from Room? In a more broader sense, how could I get info from a private field in a class to an instance of another class stored as a private field in the class.

Comment: Add a getter in the first class?

Comment: You should write a function in the first class that returns the private information. Do that on a *read-only* basis else you circumvent encapsulation.

Comment: This question can be interpreted in more than one way (as indicated by the above comments). Can you show us a code example to clarify the question?

Comment: Rough problem, can you use an ORM to maintain the relationships for you ? You wont be able to access a private variable from another class unless you use relection as @Mena mentioned

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to structure your code so that objects do not know about their encapsulators to avoid spaghetti code and circular dependencies, so maybe you can reconsider your design.  However, if a Room is to know about People and People to know about the Room they are in, then a straight forward way would be for code outside both of these objects to construct them:

```
public class House {
    private final Room room1;
    private final Room room2;

    public House() {
        Room room1 = new Room();
        Room room2 = new Room();

        People group1 = new People();
        People group2 = new People();

        group1.setRoom(room1);
        group2.setRoom(room2);

        this.room1 = room1;
        this.room2 = room2;
    }
}

public class People {
    private final Room room;

    public People(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }
}
```